# Expansion of a gas under isothermal and reversible conditions

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the reason for the statement - "When the expansion of an ideal gas is carried out under isothermal and reversible conditions, the internal energy does not change, *i.e.*, $\Delta$U=0?"

A relation with the equation ($\Delta$H=$\Delta$U-P$\Delta$V)  or ($\Delta$U = q + w) would be helpful

U = Internal Energy; H = Enthalpy; V = Volume; q = Heat gained by the system; w = Work done by the system.

Comment: For ideal gas change in internal energy(Delta U) is given by U2-U1=nCv(T2-T1). In isothermal process T1=T2. Hence U2=U1.

Comment: Note that it applies rather to a [perfect gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_gas) which is an ideal gas with the constant heat capacity.

Comment: Irreversible isothermal expansion also gives $\Delta U=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal energy is an equilibrium physical property of an ideal gas (or any other substance), independent of any process.  So it can't depend directly on q or w.  Historically, it was observed experimentally that, for gases that approached ideal gas behavior, U was a function only of temperature (not pressure or volume) and that $\Delta U$ depended only on the temperatures of the two end states.  Later, after the 2nd law of thermodynamics was developed, it was shown mathematically that, for a substance that obeys the equation of state PV=nRT, U=U(T).